# Accessing a database connection object from another class

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to implement a program where there is:

1. A MySQLConnection class that handles the database connection
2. A Screen class for the GUI that takes input to be stored in the DB
3. Main class

I want to call the MySQLConnection object created in the main method from the Screen class.

What I have attempted so far - erroneously- is as follows. Pointers to resolve this problem are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Main Class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //Start main screen
                    Screen start = new Screen(); 
                    start.setVisible(true);
                   //create db connection
                   **MySQLConnection sqlConn = new MySQLConnection();
                   Connection con=sqlConn.connectToDatabase();**
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

MySQL Connection class:

```
public class MySQLConnection {
   public Connection connectToDatabase() {//connect to db   }
   public void addToDatabase(String tableName, ArrayList<String> columns, ArrayList<String> values) {//add a row to table in db}
   public void closeConnection() {//close db connection}
}
```

AddScreen class:

```
public class Screen extends JFrame{
    ArrayList<String> mainValues= new ArrayList<String>();

    //Create GUI
    public Screen(){
        ...
        ArrayList<String> mainValues= new ArrayList<String>(); 
        String mainId = mainI.getText();
        String mainName = mainN.getText();
        mainValues.add(mainId);
        mainValues.add(mainName);
  }

    public void saveToDatabase() {
        String[] mainColumns= {"mid", "mname"};
        **con.addToDatabase("main_category", mainColumns, mainValues);**
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `Screen` class doesn't have access to the `MySQLConnection` object. There are several ways to solve this, the simplest is to simply pass the `MySQLConnection` object to the `Screen` class.

**Main:**

```
MySQLConnection sqlConn = new MySQLConnection();
Screen start = new Screen(sqlConn); 
start.setVisible(true);
```

**MySQLConnection**

```
private Connection con;

public MySQLConnection() {
    this.connectToDatabase();
}

public void connectToDatabase() { 
    this.con = //connect to db   
}

public void addToDatabase(String tableName, ArrayList<String> columns, ArrayList<String> values) {...}

public void closeConnection() {...}
```

**Screen:**

```
private MySQLConnection sqlConn ;

public Screen(MySQLConnection sqlConn){
    ...
    this.sqlConn = sqlConn;
    String mainId = mainI.getText();
    String mainName = mainN.getText();
    mainValues.add(mainId);
    mainValues.add(mainName);
}

public void saveToDatabase() {
    String[] mainColumns= {"mid", "mname"};
    sqlConn.addToDatabase("main_category", mainColumns, mainValues);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works and the explanation is clear. I get a new error "The method addToDatabase(...) is undefined for the type Connection" which can be resolved with a casting to MySQlConnection. Is there any way to manage this without a cast? Thanks!

Comment: Not really sure about your requirements. But you might want to change the design by wrapping `Connection` in `MySQLConnection`. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your main class you need to get the return value in the `Connection` object,

```
Connection con=sqlConn.connectToDatabase();
```

Now, `con` will hold the connection object . so that you can use it to query the database as normal.

Comment: Attempted. But when trying to call con from within Screen with con.addToDatabase(...), I still get "con cannot be resolved"

Comment: Editted question to reflect changes

Comment: Make sure that you have imported `java.sql.connection` class

Comment: Yes I had. Passing the connection via the constructor solved the problem.